# Why read.delim failed to skip blank lines in R

Tags: r, skip

I have a input file (`|` separated ) with the following content.

```
name|val1|val2
foo|30|20
bar||20
qux|30|
ert|12|11
uyt||
```

What I want to do is to extract lines only when every fields
contain value. Yielding this:

```
foo|30|20
ert|12|11
```

Why the following doesn't work:

```
data<-read.delim("myinput.txt",sep="|",na.strings="",
                  header=TRUE,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,fill=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file isn't too big to be read into memory at first, you can easily fix this with:

```
data <- data[complete.cases(data), ]
```

Also, you don't have any lines that are *blank*, you just have lines where some cells have missing values, which isn't quite the same thing, and it's not really covered by the `blank.lines.skip` argument.